# cat /proc/meminfo what do all those numbers mean

Tags: linux, filesystems, operating-systems, proc

In reading the man page on the [free](http://linux.die.net/man/1/free) command in Linux. I found that is gets its info from `/proc/meminfo.`

I understand a few of the entries, like `MemTotal` and `MemFree`. What do the rest mean.

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        3973736 kB
MemFree:          431064 kB
Buffers:           46604 kB
Cached:           494648 kB
SwapCached:        11360 kB
Active:          2322760 kB
Inactive:         933028 kB
Active(anon):    2057952 kB
Inactive(anon):   679956 kB
Active(file):     264808 kB
Inactive(file):   253072 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
SwapTotal:       4096568 kB
SwapFree:        3961748 kB
Dirty:               236 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2704520 kB
Mapped:           182240 kB
Shmem:             23372 kB
Slab:              93848 kB
SReclaimable:      52044 kB
SUnreclaim:        41804 kB
KernelStack:        5064 kB
PageTables:        64928 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6083436 kB
Committed_AS:    7327800 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      321156 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359411708 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      225280 kB
DirectMap2M:     3895296 kB
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I got the following from the CentOS documentation:

> Much of the information here is used by the `free`, `top`, and `ps`
> commands. In fact, the output of the `free` command is similar in
> appearance to the contents and structure of `/proc/meminfo`. But by
> looking directly at `/proc/meminfo`, more details are revealed:
>
> MemTotal — Total amount of physical RAM, in kilobytes.
>
> MemFree — The amount of physical RAM, in kilobytes, left unused by the
> system.
>
> Buffers — The amount of physical RAM, in kilobytes, used for file
> buffers.
>
> Cached — The amount of physical RAM, in kilobytes, used as cache
> memory.
>
> SwapCached — The amount of swap, in kilobytes, used as cache memory.
>
> Active — The total amount of buffer or page cache memory, in
> kilobytes, that is in active use. This is memory that has been
> recently used and is usually not reclaimed for other purposes.
>
> Inactive — The total amount of buffer or page cache memory, in
> kilobytes, that are free and available. This is memory that has not
> been recently used and can be reclaimed for other purposes.
>
> HighTotal and HighFree — The total and free amount of memory, in
> kilobytes, that is not directly mapped into kernel space. The
> HighTotal value can vary based on the type of kernel used.
>
> LowTotal and LowFree — The total and free amount of memory, in
> kilobytes, that is directly mapped into kernel space. The LowTotal
> value can vary based on the type of kernel used.
>
> SwapTotal — The total amount of swap available, in kilobytes.
>
> SwapFree — The total amount of swap free, in kilobytes.
>
> Dirty — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, waiting to be
> written back to the disk.
>
> Writeback — The total amount of memory, in
> kilobytes, actively being written back to the disk.
>
> Mapped — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, which have been
> used to map devices, files, or libraries using the `mmap` command.
>
> Slab — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, used by the kernel to
> cache data structures for its own use.
>
> Committed_AS — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, estimated to
> complete the workload. This value represents the worst case scenario
> value, and also includes swap memory.
>
> PageTables — The total amount of
> memory, in kilobytes, dedicated to the lowest page table level.
>
> VMallocTotal — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, of total
> allocated virtual address space.
>
> VMallocUsed — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, of used
> virtual address space.
>
> VMallocChunk — The largest contiguous block of memory, in kilobytes,
> of available virtual address space.
>
> HugePages_Total — The total number of hugepages for the system. The
> number is derived by dividing Hugepagesize by the megabytes set aside
> for hugepages specified in `/proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_pool`. *This statistic
> only appears on the x86, Itanium, and AMD64 architectures.*
>
> HugePages_Free — The total number of hugepages available for the
> system. *This statistic only appears on the x86, Itanium, and AMD64
> architectures.*
>
> Hugepagesize — The size for each hugepages unit in kilobytes. By
> default, the value is 4096 KB on uniprocessor kernels for 32 bit
> architectures. For SMP, hugemem kernels, and AMD64, the default is
> 2048 KB. For Itanium architectures, the default is 262144 KB. *This
> statistic only appears on the x86, Itanium, and AMD64 architectures.*

These articles give a great explanation of the information in `/proc/meminfo`:

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.rst
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-meminfo

Comment: `For Itanium architectures, the default is 262144 KB.` - Should that be 262144 bytes?

Comment: The third link does no longer exist ("404").

Comment: @Michael: I know this is ancient history, and I can’t confirm that they are accurate, but multiple versions ([1](https://web.archive.org/web/20181121191730/http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-meminfo.html), [2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/reference_guide/s2-proc-meminfo) and [3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-meminfo)) of the Red Hat document say “For Itanium architectures, the default is 262144 KB.”

Comment: hugepage note: AnonHugePages can be > 0 even if HugePages_Total is zero, because they are different mechanisms of allocating huge pages

Answer (score 2):

An important note about the "kB" sizes:

> While the file shows kilobytes (kB; 1 kB equals 1000 B), it is
> actually kibibytes (KiB; 1 KiB equals 1024 B). This imprecision in
> `/proc/meminfo` is known, but is not corrected due to legacy concerns -
> programs rely on `/proc/meminfo` to specify size with the "kB" string.

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-meminfo)