# How to only show specific information from `free`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-usage

I am using this command

```
free --mega
```

to show free memory and free swap. It shows `total`, `used`, `free`, `shared`, `buff/cache` and `available`. How do I get it to just show free memory for both only?

Answer (score 1):

#### Parsing `free`

> How do I get it to just show free memory for both only?

There is no option that does it. You need to parse the output.

`free` is not specified by POSIX. By your description I assume `free --mega` gives you something like this:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           4126        1624         116           5        2386        2227
Swap:          2146        1554         592
```

But it's different in [this question from 2013](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68526/108618):

> ```
>              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
> Mem:          2496       2260        236          0          5        438
> -/+ buffers/cache:       1816        680
> Swap:         1949         68       1881
> ```

I don't know how many implementations of `free` exist. In general different implementations may use different formats. The question is tagged `ubuntu`, this narrows it to a certain implementation. Still the format may change in the future. For this reason parsing the output of `free` is not totally reliable.

To get only the two numbers under `free`, pick the 4th column from all lines but the first:

```
free --mega | awk 'NR!=1 {print $4}'
```

Maybe you want to keep the header. The string `free` in the first line is visually in the 4th column, but formally (in the understanding of `awk`) it's in the 3rd. Use this:

```
free --mega | awk '{print NR==1?$3:$4}'
```

And maybe you want to keep the first column:

```
free --mega | awk '
  NR==1 {$0="dUm "$0}
  {print $1" "$4}
' | column -t | sed 's/^dUm/   /'
```

Here `dUm` is a dummy string designed to shift the first row, so `free` ends up in the formal 4th column. Above we used `awk` without this trick, but now `column -t` requires it.

The following code uses [few](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25144/108618) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18022947/10765659) tricks and allows you to pick or rearrange columns, or even calculate custom ones, all this by referring to their names:

```
LC_ALL=C free --mega | awk '
  NR==1 {
    $0="dUm"$0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { lbl=$i; sub(" *$", "", lbl); ix[lbl]=i}
  }
  { $0=$0" dUm dUm dUm"
    print "x "$1" "$ix["free"]" "(NR==1?"%free":int(100*$ix["free"]/$ix["total"])"%")" "$ix["available"]" "$ix["total"]
  }' | rev | column -t | rev | sed -e 's/dUm/   /g' -e 's/^x  //'
```

`LC_ALL=C` is in case `free` is localized.

---

#### Reading `/proc/meminfo`

Alternatively you can read values from [`/proc/meminfo`](https://superuser.com/q/521551/432690). Its format is somewhat easier to parse and it should be stable (i.e. it should not change in the future). Example:

```
</proc/meminfo grep -E '^(Mem|Swap)Free:'
```

The output will be like:

```
MemFree:          118380 kB
SwapFree:         531196 kB
```

It says `kB` and some documentation says the values are "in kilobytes", but actually these are [kibibytes](https://superuser.com/a/373601/432690). This ambiguity [is not going to be fixed](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/666444/).

If you want megabytes (`free --mega` in your question uses megabytes) then you should recalculate accordingly:

```
</proc/meminfo awk '$1~"^(Mem|Swap)Free:" {$2=$2*1024/1000000; $3="MB"; print}' | column -t
```

or maybe just:

```
</proc/meminfo awk '$1~"^(Mem|Swap)Free:" {$2=int($2*1024/1000000); $3=""; print}' | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemFree\|SwapFree"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
free -h | awk '{print NR==1?$3:$1$4}'
```

will give you:

```
free  
Mem:30G  
Swap:14G
```